# Reference for information theory and bayesian inference

Tags: reference-request, statistical-inference, information-theory, bayesian

I'm taking a course in Bayesian inference and Information Theory with application to physics. I have taken courses in Probability, Statistics, Measure Theory and Statistical Mechanics.

I would like a book mathematically rigorous but illustrated with physical examples if possible. In case it is not, what is a good book for learning about information theory and bayesian inference in more depth with the forementioned background?

Answer (score 7):

```
1. M. Jordan (ed.), Learning in Graphical Models , MIT Press, 1998
```

Overview of the book:

> Graphical models, a marriage between probability theory and graph theory,
>   provide a natural tool for dealing with two problems that occur
>   throughout applied mathematics and engineering—uncertainty and
>   complexity. In particular, they play an increasingly important role in
>   the design and analysis of machine learning algorithms. Fundamental to
>   the idea of a graphical model is the notion of modularity: a complex
>   system is built by combining simpler parts. Probability theory serves
>   as the glue whereby the parts are combined, ensuring that the system
>   as a whole is consistent and providing ways to interface models to
>   data. Graph theory provides both an intuitively appealing interface by
>   which humans can model highly interacting sets of variables and a data
>   structure that lends itself naturally to the design of efficient
>   general-purpose algorithms.
>
> This book presents an in-depth exploration of issues related to
>   learning within the graphical model formalism. Four chapters are
>   tutorial chapters—Robert Cowell on Inference for Bayesian Networks,
>   David MacKay on Monte Carlo Methods, Michael I. Jordan et al. on
>   Variational Methods, and David Heckerman on Learning with Bayesian
>   Networks. The remaining chapters cover a wide range of topics of
>   current research interest.

```
2. M. Mezard and A. Montanari, Information, Physics and Computation , Oxford University Press, 2009
```

Overview of this book:

> This book presents a unified approach to a rich and rapidly evolving
>   research domain at the interface between statistical physics,
>   theoretical computer science/discrete mathematics, and
>   coding/information theory. It is accessible to graduate students and
>   researchers without a specific training in any of these fields. The
>   selected topics include spin glasses, error correcting codes,
>   satisfiability, and are central to each field. The approach focuses on
>   large random instances and adopts a common probabilistic formulation
>   in terms of graphical models. It presents message passing algorithms
>   like belief propagation and survey propagation, and their use in
>   decoding and constraint satisfaction solving. It also explains
>   analysis techniques like density evolution and the cavity method, and
>   uses them to study phase transitions.

```
3. C. Bishop, Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (Information Science and Statistics), 2010
```

Overview of this book:

> This is the first textbook on pattern recognition to present the
>   Bayesian viewpoint. The book presents approximate inference algorithms
>   that permit fast approximate answers in situations where exact answers
>   are not feasible. It uses graphical models to describe probability
>   distributions when no other books apply graphical models to machine
>   learning. No previous knowledge of pattern recognition or machine
>   learning concepts is assumed. Familiarity with multivariate calculus
>   and basic linear algebra is required, and some experience in the use
>   of probabilities would be helpful though not essential as the book
>   includes a self-contained introduction to basic probability theory.

These books are self-contained and thus the prerequisites mentioned in the details are a add-on for research in these areas. Of course these are just the subset of many other content-rich books out there.

Hope this helps.